# $q.all() multiple calls in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a function that invokes on click event. It has a list of drivers and i want ETA against each driver through Google direction service. Here's my code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var urlCalls = [];

function getDriversEta(jobLoc, drivers) { //this function gets invoke on click.
    angular.forEach(drivers, function (value, key) {
        value.eta = undefined;
        urlCalls.push(GetDriverMatrix(jobLoc.lat, jobLoc.lon,
            value.Location.Latitude, value.Location.Longitude, function (response) {
                value.eta = formatSecondsToTime(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value);
                deferred.resolve(value);
            }));
    });
    $q.all(urlCalls).then(
        function (results) {
            var check = results;
        },
        function (errors) {
            //deferred.reject(errors);
        },
        function (updates) {
            //deferred.update(updates);
        });
}

function GetDriverMatrix(pickupLat, pickupLon, driverLat, driverLon, callBack) {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRequest = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(driverLat, driverLon),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(pickupLat, pickupLon),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };
    directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            callBack(response);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

it works fine the first time but gives repeated values. But on the second click event then function of $q.all() fires before the callback response. What am i doing wrong here? I am new to promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple problems:

1) You are doing multiple asynchronous things, but you've only got one deferred object, which is being used by all of them. So as soon as any one of them resolves that deferred, they'll effectively all be resolved. Instead, they each need their own.
2) GetDriverMatrix seems to be doing both a callback approach and a promise approach at the same time. Pick just one (I recommend promises).

So let's start by fixing up GetDriveMatrix:

```
//** Callback parameter removed
function getDriverMatrix(pickupLat, pickupLon, driverLat, driveLon) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); //** create a new deferred each time
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRequest = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(driverLat, driverLon),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(pickupLat, pickupLon),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };
    directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        deferred.resolve(response); //** resolve instead of calling callback
    } else {
        deferred.reject(response); //** reject if there's an error
    }
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Now to use it, you're mostly on the right track, but there are few things i would change:

1) Since i removed the callback part of getDriverMatrix, we'll use the promise instead.
2) Have the array of promises be inside the function, not outside it. No one else needs to see the array, so there's no need to expose it
3) Instead of doing a foreach and then pushing into an array, i would use array.map. It's designed exactly for cases like this, and saves you from doing the pushing manually.

```
function getDriversEta(jobLoc, drivers) {
    //** Using array.map to produce a new array of promises
    var promises = drivers.map(function (driver) {
        return GetDriverMatrix(jobLoc.lat, jobLoc.lon, driver.Location.latitude, driver.Location.longitude)
            //** using the .then method instead of callback
            .then(function (response) {
                driver.eta = formatSecondsToTime(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value);
                return driver;
            });
    });

    $q.all(promises).then(
        function (results) {
            var check = results;
        },
        function (errors) {

        },
        function (updates) {

        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you taught me today the use of .map function and each asynchronous call should have their own differed object but it's throwing an error for now that states:
`Cannot read property then of undefined`

P.S: I need to know why did you use promise over callback, why not use callback?

Comment: Okay i got it, there was a mistake in `getDriverMatrix` function. It was returning a promise inside the `directionsService response`. So i had to move the `return deferred.promise;` to the end of the function and it worked. Thanks Sir Cheers.

Comment: `why did you use promise over callback, why not use callback?` They both have similar goals: do some work once some other work is done. But mixing them can be painful, and promises are the easier of the two to work with, because 1) They can be easily chained, and don't result in Callback Hell 2) They significantly simplify error handling 3) you can pass the promise object to other parts of your code without that other code needing to know how the work was done originally.